# Расстояние между элементом и тенью CSS

Tags: css

Возможно ли между элементом и его тенью задать какое расстояние как это показано на рисунке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ой.. А я уже начал думать, что поторопился с ответом и надо было именно по диагонали измерить расстояние...

Comment: Скорее я поторопился с вопросом, спасибо за ответ, в любом случае.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  background: blue;
  box-shadow: 4em 4em 0 0 green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```